# Fit variable-length divs in rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this: [**http://jsfiddle.net/o0na46er/1/**](http://jsfiddle.net/o0na46er/1/)

The problem with simply using `display: inline-block` is that it leaves big spaces to the right of the container.

How can I fit the divs, using JavaScript/jQuery, in the container such that it fits them as best it can to take up the whole width of the container?

Comment: The CSS3 flexbox specification is designed specifically for layout requirements like this.

Answer (score 0):

Float them.

```css
.container {
    width: 230px;
    padding: 35px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    overflow:hidden; /* so that it expands to fit its floated contents */
}

.block {
    float:left; /* make them float to avoid the whitespace affecting the layout */
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: white;
    background: red;
    margin-right: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="block">lorem</div>
    <div class="block">consectetur</div>
    <div class="block">adipiscing</div>
    <div class="block">eiusmod</div>
    <div class="block">tempor</div>
    <div class="block">commodo</div>
    <div class="block">aute</div>
    <div class="block">dolorem</div>
    <div class="block">velit</div>
    <div class="block">porro</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o0na46er/5/

Comment: I'm looking more for something like the div version of this plugin: http://ed-lea.github.io/jquery-collagePlus/

Answer (score 0):

You should float your blocks to the left. See this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/o0na46er/4/

```
.container {
    width: 230px;
    padding: 35px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
}

.block {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: white;
    background: red;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I'm looking more for something like the div version of this plugin: http://ed-lea.github.io/jquery-collagePlus/

Comment: Have you tried using that plugin, and changing the code to apply to divs instead of images?